# Prevent error messages logged by system framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

The following message keeps getting logged to the console:

```
-[__NSCFSet minusSet:]: This app appears to be calling this method with
        a non-set parameter. Please wait while the system corrects this...
```

I don't know what I did to this appear. I never call this function and don't know what things call this.

For me, this appear when a touch anything in my UIWebView. This can be a touch in text box, or just a simple touch in any area of the page. Any new touch will produce it.

Anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately, iOS 5 is under NDA, so we really can't discuss much here. I think your best bet is to [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com), and maybe to ask some of us in the developer forums if you are stumped.

Comment: @Jonathon OP's problem can be asked and answered without reference to iOS 5, so it seems on topic here. Filing a bug and asking over at the dev forums are still very good ideas!

Comment: I am doing it, was a good idea, but until now, no answer :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find out whether your code is causing the log message or not. You can do this by interrupting the app when the message is logged and looking at the stack backtrace of the logging thread. Then, investigate what code created the object that is prompting the log message using malloc history or Instruments.

To start with, you can try adding a symbolic breakpoint on `-[__NSCFSet minusSet:]`. You could narrow it down to the actual code doing the logging if you looked at the disassembly for a call to `NSLog` and placed the breakpoint there.

Once you've ruled out your code, it's not your fault: it's time to file a bug report and move on. If the log messages are swamping more interesting log messages, you might try patching the binary so it doesn't log, but just living with it is likely to be easier (though much less fun).